# Regex Groups - Select Text Preceding Email address

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to text regex pattern.

Am trying to use this regex pattern to get various parts of email address and the text preceding it.

```
(.{1,20})([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})
```

If you move mouse over the blue highlighted text then you'll see that there is a problem with group1 and group2..

Please use this text as as an example.

```
Zak - asdasdsad@gmail.com (use first). Cell 

ssadsada, sadashdjksahjd@gmail.com, and cc: gfhfghgfh@gmail.com.  Include a
specific time for the following:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want: [Regex Example](http://regexr.com?31ka6)

```
(([\w]*[\s-\.]?[\S\s]){1,2})\s([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})

Group1: Zak -
Group2: asdasdsad
Group3: gmail.
Group4: com
```